# How to generate CSK file for BlackBerry 10 WebWorks SDK 2.0 and higher

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks

I am  working on code sign using BlackBerry 10 WebWorks SDK 2.0 from the url. https://www.blackberry.com/SignedKeys/codesigning.html

But when we try to select the following option “**For BlackBerry 10 apps developed using a BlackBerry SDK 10.2 or Higher, or BlackBerry 10 WebWorks SDK 2.0 and higher, or any apps repackaged using the BlackBerry repackaging tools for Android 1.6.1 or higher**" It's not allowing to generate CSK file instead it is redirecting  to login page even if you are logged in to the site.

Can i please know what is the issue or is their any alternate way to generate CSK file.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you don't need a CSK file any more. You can create a debug token and sign your application using your BlackBerry ID. More info here: http://devblog.blackberry.com/2013/08/code-signing-keys-be-gone-welcome-blackberry-id/

Comment: I have Installed Webworks SDK ,I am using phonegap to build the blackberry application file, Can i sign the .bar file without csk files ?